# PDO return $row from a class method

Tags: oop, methods, pdo

Hey guys I am learning OOP in php. I come across some issue, when I try to customize PDO in my own class. Basically I have tried to return the row and fetch it outside my class. Unfortunately I would not work. I get this error ***"Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object".*** Have a look and give me some tips if You can. Many thanks.

```
$connection = new MySql(DBUSER, DBPASS);
$row = $connection->query("select * from users", "name");
while($row->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "<p>". $row["name"] ."</p>";
}
```

And here is how the MySql class look like:

```
class MySql{
    private $dbc;
    private $user;
    private $pass;

    function __construct($user="root", $pass=""){
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->pass = $pass;    
    try{
       $this->dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=DBNAME;charset=utf8", $user, $pass);
        }
    catch(PDOException $e){
       echo $e->getMessage();
       echo "Problem z Połączeniem do MySql sprawdź haslo i uzytkownika";
        }
    }
    public function query($query, $c1=""){
    $mysqlquery = $this->dbc->prepare($query);
    $mysqlquery->execute();
    return $row = $mysqlquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    /* I WANT TO PERFORM COMENTED CODE OUTSIDE THE CLASS
    while($row = $mysqlquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        if($c1!=""){
        echo "<p>". $row[$c1] ."</p>";
        }
    }
    */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return `$mysqlquery` to iterate over it, you have to return `$mysqlquery`, not just one row.

Here is a better version of your class, with dramatically improved error handling and security. But still awful configurability though.

```
class MySql{
    private $dbc;

    function __construct($user="root", $pass=""){
        $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost; dbname=DBNAME;charset=utf8";
        $opt = array(
           PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
           PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
        );
       $this->dbc = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
    }
    public function query($query, $data = array()){
        $stm = $this->dbc->prepare($query);
        $stm->execute($data);
        return $stm;
    }
}

$connection = new MySql(DBUSER, DBPASS);
$stm = $connection->query("select * from users WHERE name = ?", array("name"));
while($row = $stm->fetch()){
    echo "<p>". $row["name"] ."</p>";
}
```

Comment: Great. It works. I now apply security tips to my code and customize your code to my needs.

Thanks again.
Regards